# French poetry with a singsongy feel to it

Tags: poésie

Who would be the French poet, or what would be the work of French poetry, which has the following characteristic to the most noticeable degree:  It--

- has a simple and strict meter
- and a singsongy feel to it
- so that a beginning student hearing it can readily perceive the line breaks even without understanding the meaning?

For example, it probably would not be Fontaine's Fables because the number of syllables per line varies too much.

I have so formulated the question that one can actually try to answer it; but would also appreciate any helpful suggestions--names of poets, poems, a particular style, links to a reading, etc.  Thank you.

Comment: Charles Baudelaire FTW.

Answer (score 2):

Je propose par exemple :

- [Paul Verlaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Verlaine)
- [Arthur Rimbaud](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Rimbaud)

chantés par [Léo Ferré](https://www.google.fr/search?q=leo%20ferre%20rimbaud&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=25EtWLeaNar_8AfO3orQCA)

Answer (score 2):

You can look at everything that is a [*poème à forme fixe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formes_fixes): sonnets, rondeaux, ballades, etc.
They all have a strict meter and perceiving the line breaks can be easy if they are declaimed.